# Laravel sql anywhere connection error in ubuntu apache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, sybase, sqlanywhere

The error text is :

```
sasql_connect(): The SQLAnywhere client libraries could not be loaded. Please ensure that libdbcapi_r.so can be found in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
```

I get this error when I run the code as a Laravel Job. However, SQL Anywhere connection is successful if I write a controller function.

I think, if there was a problem about my SQL Anywhere installation, I would face the same error in the controller function.

I am trying to find a solution for 3 days without hope.

All replies will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that the extension is installed and turned on for all php installations - the one running the job is likely not the one your web server is running.

Comment: To debug this you can queue a job that dumps `phpinfo()` to a file and compare that with the output of `phpinfo()` from the web interface to see what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks,
How can I turn on the extension for all php installation?

And @apokryfos thank, I will do that

Comment: @muhammedsafayaşar ideally you wouldn't really need to if you can manage to get bot the queue and the web interface to use the same PHP installation. Usually this is a problem with which php binary is put in the `/usr/bin` path.

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos.
Yes there is a difference between apache and jobs. Apache uses /etc/php/5.6/apache2 whereas job queue uses /etc/php/5.6/cli. And in phpinfo that I wrote in a file by job queue, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not defined. But I do not know how to set it for php/5.6/cli.

Can you help about that?

Comment: Edit the PHP.ini in /etc/PHP/5.6/cli and make it look like the one in /etc/PHP/5.6/apache2

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks a lot. But didn't work. I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I see it in phpinfo generated by laravel job. But didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: I found a solution. The problem was not about php versions. It was because supervisor (I use it for monitoring queued jobs). 
I set environment variable in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/my-worker.conf
"environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64"
After updating supervisor ("supervisorctl update") everything worked well.

Thanks a lot @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was not about php versions. It was because supervisor (I use it for monitoring queued jobs). I set environment variable in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/my-worker.conf` `environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64` After updating supervisor ("supervisorctl update") everything worked well.